# iptables lets SYN/ACK packet through without having received a SYN packet before. Is this behavior normal?

Tags: tcp, firewall, iptables, behavior

In my scenario a SYN packet is sent to a web server in LAN1 via an out-of-band channel. The web server responds via the default gateway where an iptables firewall is configured. In my understanding the firewall should block the SYN/ACK packet of the webserver because it hasn't seen a SYN packet before, but i am observing iptables forwarding the packet back to the client in LAN2. Is this the expected behavior of a SPI firewall? I think not, right?

My iptables rules are the following:
It is configured so that only established connections are allowed.

```
    # Completed on Fri Jul 31 15:31:58 2020
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Fri Jul 31 15:31:58 2020
    *filter
    :INPUT DROP [10:4983]`enter code here`
    :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
    :OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
    -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -p udp -m udp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISH`enter code here`ED -j ACCEPT

    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

```
                     1. SYN (out of band channel)
           +------------------------------------------------+
           |                                                |
           |                                                |
           v                 +-----------+                  |
    +------+-----+           |           |          +-------+----+
    |            | 2. SYN/ACK| iptabeles | SYN/ACK? |            |
    | Webserver  +---------->+ Firewall  +--------->+   Client   |
    |            |           |           |          |            |
    +------------+           +-----------+          +------------+
     10.0.0.0/24                                    192.168.10.0/24
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: `-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT` - This is your first rule and it forwards everything from the network where the web server is, no matter if belonging to an established connection or not.

Answer (score 0):

it's a good question and it shows that you have some knowledge about iptables and TCP. But the thing is that iptables and netfilter works in different rules, and for the deny of outter connection quest is bound to NAT table. In the rules you showed above, there isn't any NAT table rules, so it can go into the client without any obstcle.

Answer (score 0):

iptables (aka netfilter) is a stateless packet filter by default. That is why if you want to turn on stateful features, the `--conn` or `--state` parameters are used, and they must be placed up in the ACL. Another thing to note is that iptables does not implement an implicit deny rule by default. You must add one at the bottom of each chain.

In your case, the firs rule `-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT` will forward everything from source `10.0.0.0/24` to any destination regardless. Subsequent rules do not matter is this case.

To make it work, you should re-arrange the first rule and place it last in your ACL. In other words, the placement of rules in the ACL is very important. Place specific rules first, and end with "catch-all" rules last. In this example `-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT` is a catch-all rule and must be placed at the bottom of the ACL.